# Get my Firemonkey app (Tokyo R3) to deploy to my test device

Tags: ios, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a test app I've built with FireMonkey (Tokyo 10.2 R3). It builds fine and deploys for Android and seems to build fine for iOS (no errors in the build portion anyway).

When it finally tries to deploy to my device (iPhone 6s Plus - 64bit - iOS11), the deploy process ends in a "e8000067" error, with nothing added to the phone.

The certificates appear to be fine (occasionally I get an "e8008015" error, but looking at them in the Provisioning Page seems to make that error go away).

Else where I see indications that e8000067 could relate to trying to install a 64bit version on a 32 bit device. But this is certainly a 64bit phone.

How can I get past this error and deploy to my test device.

Comment: I have also experienced this error when the provisioning profile was not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My resolution...

Create a brand new provisioning Development Provisioning Profile on developer.apple.com.

After that was completed and installed both the original and the new one would allow the app to deploy to the phone.

Why it worked, I don't know. I'm hypothesizing that it has something to do with the switch to mandatory Xcode 9/iOS 11 builds. Because at one point, it worked with the original profile and certificates (as well as straight builds with Xcode being happy).